# How to make label background circle in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I made the label background a circle
I succeeded in creating a circle using the code below

```
lbNumber.layer.masksToBounds = true
lbNumber.layer.cornerRadius = lbNumber1.frame.width/2
```

But in the simulator's iphone8, the circle looks distorted as in the photo.
Is there any way to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(1) Do not use corner radius to round things. Use a mask. (2) Do not run the rounding code until you know what the frame is really going to be. The problem with your code is that you are running your code too soon (probably in `viewDidLoad`), when the true frame is not yet known.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's inside

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  lbNumber.layer.cornerRadius = lbNumber1.frame.height/2
}
```

Also verify that `width = height` for the label